# How to make a tkinter input box and close it?

Tags: python, tkinter

PYTHON
I couldn't fit whole problem in the title so here it is:

I am trying to make a tkinter box that accepts input and closes after input has been accepted that can simply be done by the root.destroy() command, but that is not the problem. I am trying to make the input (the user gave) accessible through-out my code. Whenever I try to use the return statement it is never is noticed because the root.destroy() command it before it. Same thing vice versa.

```
from tkinter import *
score = 0
root = Tk()
nameLabel = Label(root, text="Name")
ent = Entry(root, bd=5)

def getName():
    global score
    entt= (ent.get())
    score = 1
    root.destroy()
    return entt

b1 = Button(root, text='FirstC', command=getName)
b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=15)

nameLabel.pack()
ent.pack()

root.mainloop()
print(func1())
```

ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\14753\OneDrive\Desktop\Stocks\trying.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(getName())
  File "C:\Users\14753\OneDrive\Desktop\Stocks\trying.py", line 9, in getName
    entt= (ent.get())
  File "C:\Users\14753\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2682, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!entry"
```

I have been going at this problem for a little while now any help would be very helpful!

Comment: What is `func1`?

Comment: code works correctly for me. Except `func1` which it can't find.

Comment: `return entt` is not noticed because `Button` runs this function and it has no method to get this value. You have to assign `entt` to global variable and later use this variable outside function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Button` runs function but it has no method to get returned value. In function you have to assign text from `Entry` to global variable and later use this variable outside function.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def get_name():
    global name # inform function to use global variable instead of creating local one

    name = name_entry.get() # assign text to global variable

    root.destroy()

# --- main ---

name = ''  # global variable with default value (if you don't put name)

root = tk.Tk()

name_label = tk.Label(root, text='Name')
name_label.pack()

name_entry = tk.Entry(root)
name_entry.pack(side='right')

b = tk.Button(root, text='First', command=get_name)
b.pack(side='left')

root.mainloop()

print('name:', name) # display text from global variable
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This was really helpful and for anyone asking the "func1" was what another function was called before I condensed the code